# JavaScript car movement with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

We are using a combination of TweenMax and Scroll Magic to Achieve the car moving on the Road effect

Here is the fiddle I've created

[Car movement fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a05npoyp/15/)

If you scroll down the road and then scroll up just a little bit, you will notice that the car continues its journey down the road but in reverse. This is because the orientation of the car is linked to the last scroll direction of the mouse.
We would like to make the following function to improve the way the car drives on the website. I’ve used Psudo Code as I think the logic I have in mind is correct I just don’t know the right commands/functions/syntax. Of course if anyone has a more elegant suggestion I’m all ears.

(See how the car interacts when changing direction on http://rit-team.ru/ )

Var CarDirection = “S” - Vehicle direction is set to south

```
Upon Mouse Scroll()
{
VehicleYPosition = Get Current Object Position() // This is the current  location of the car on the page. even if it is mid tween.
ScrollYPosition = Get Current Scroll Position() // This tells us where the scroll is currently on the page. I know this relates to scroll magic but if you can advise on this too it would be really appreciated.

If MouseScroll = Up AND CarDirection = “S” AND VehicleYPosition + 20 < ScrollYPosition{
    Stop Current Tween ()
    RunFigure8 Tween (CarDirection) // this would consist of using the car’s current position and direction to drive in a figure 8 motion to turn the car around (see http://rit-team.ru/)
    CarDirection = “N” // Change the orientation of the car
    RunRegularTweenFunction()   // The car will then continue driving to the correct scroll location 
}

If MouseScroll = Down AND CarDirection = “N” AND VehicleYPosition - 20 > ScrollYPosition{
    Stop Current Tween ()
    RunFigure8 Tween (CarDirection)
    CarDirection = “S”
    RunRegularTweenFunction()   
}
```

}

Thank you

Comment: you need to create an example in `jsfiddle` so that we can work on it.. This code isn't sufficient..

Comment: Here. 
https://jsfiddle.net/a05npoyp/13/

Comment: the turn animation can be done with css key frames, and is just set to run when ever the car turns.